# Matlab 7.0.0 fail to run an application

Tags: vb.net, matlab, activex

I try to launch a program in Matlab 7.0.0. 
The program was coded under Matlab 7.0.0, Also I install Visual Basic 6 because the program required an ActiveX. The OS is XP in VirtualBox.
But the program didn't work.
The Error is :

> ??? Too many outputs requested.  Most likely cause is missing [] around
>   left hand side that has a comma separated list expansion.
>
> Error in ==> esfa>esfa_OpeningFcn at 59
>   h=varargin{:};
>
> Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 153
>       feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});
>
> Error in ==> esfa at 44
>       gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>   Any Help please?
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some words on what is "the program"? where does it fail? some code of it?

Comment: the program implement Fuzzy C-mean, However this program work pefectely on the other computer with any problem.

Comment: Can you paste only the line that you type for calling the program?

Comment: yes of course, I call the file by it name:    esfa

Comment: I have the same file with extension .fig, and it work perfectly when I try to run it.

Comment: This function shouldn't have any outputs?

Comment: The program works if you run it from the "Run" button?

Comment: I send you the whole program if you want to try launch it?

Comment: I guess that the problem is in same configuration, but I can't find it!

Comment: No, it didn't work! @Adiel